# Snapshot folder Access

Tags: sql-server, replication, snapshot

I have set up a Transaction Replication, with the distribution server as subscriber itself and implemented pull subscription, to avoid load on my publisher.

When I created publisher at my source server, I got snapshot agent error saying that it cannot access the default `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` folder location. So I changed and gave a file location at Subscriber `E:\` drive and it worked.

My question here is, if it is pull subscription with distribution server as subscribe:

- Where should the snapshot folder be?

Because I see access issue.

Please comment if I am not clear.

Comment: You mentioned it is working when you are using `E:\' drive on subscriber. Then you said you are getting error. Are you looking for best practice advise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have used the default location by mentioning it an `UNC` path. `Snapshot Agent job` will need write and `Distribution Agent job` will need read privilege. Snapshot file location (directory) is a property of `Publication`, keep that in mind when you mention alternate location.

When configuring a Distributor through the Configure Distribution Wizard or the New Publication Wizard, the snapshot folder defaults to a local path: X:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL\ReplData. If you are using a remote Distributor or pull subscriptions, you must specify a UNC network share (such as \\snapshot) rather than a local path.

Reference:

- [Specify an Alternate Snapshot Folder Location (SQL Server Management
  Studio)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/publish/specify-an-alternate-snapshot-folder-location-sql-server-management-studio?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Alternate Snapshot Folder Locations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/alternate-snapshot-folder-locations?view=sql-server-2017)

> The Snapshot Agent must have write permissions for the directory you
>   specify, and the Distribution Agent or Merge Agent must have read
>   permissions. If pull subscriptions are used, you must specify a shared
>   directory as a universal naming convention (UNC) path, such as
>   \computername\snapshot.

Alternate snapshot locations enable you to store snapshot files in a location other than, or in addition to, the default location, which is typically located on the Distributor. Alternate locations can be on another server, on a network drive, or on removable media such as CD-ROMs or removable disks.

More about securing snapshot folder.

[Secure the Snapshot Folder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/security/secure-the-snapshot-folder?view=sql-server-2017)

Comment: As per your comment,default location of snapshot folder is in Distributor(in my case distributor is at subscriber),so it will be `D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL` in Distributor.So when i create publisher,the snapshot agent should have access to snapshot folder in distributor.Am i correct?

Comment: Modified my answer based on  your comment.